# A few questions about histogram plot

Tags: plotting, legending, histograms

Consider the following plot:

```
CDFforPoisson[u_] = x /. Solve[Exp[-x/0.01] == u, x][[1]];
DistrData = CDFforPoisson@RandomReal[{0, 1}, 10^6];
Histogram[{DistrData}, 100, "ProbabilityDensity", Frame -> True, 
 ChartStyle -> {Opacity[.25, Red], Opacity[.25, Blue], 
   Opacity[.25, Darker@Green]}, FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, 18], 
 ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log"}, ImageSize -> Large, 
 PlotRange -> {{0.0001, 0.03}, All}, 
 FrameLabel -> {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(l\), \(\(displ\)\(.\)\)]\) \
[mm]", "Fraction"}, 
 PlotLabel -> 
  Style[Row[{"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(l\), \(decay\)]\) = 0.01 mm"}], 18,
    Black], ChartLegends -> Placed[{"Before IP"}, {0.2, 0.9}]]
```

[image]

It has two problems: small font of legends, and a bin going out of the plot frame (on the right). Could you please tell me how to adjust the font of the legend, and how to avoid the frame problem?

Comment: For the legend size try e.g. `Placed[{Style["Before IP", 16]}, ...]` where `16` is the font size.

Comment: How is `CDFforPoisson` related to a Poisson distribution?  The only thing I can come up with is that `CDFforPoisson[u]` gives one-hundredth of the mean of a Poisson distribution whose probability of obtaining zero is `u`.  Also, `Solve` is not necessary as the result is `- Log[u]/100`.

Answer (score 2):

1. Using `PlotRangePadding`, space can be created around the histogram.
2. Using `LegendMarkerSize` for a `SwatchLegend`, the size of the legend can be changed. You can also use `Style` as has been suggested without altering your code much.

---

```
Histogram[{DistrData}, 100, "ProbabilityDensity"
 , Frame -> True
 , ChartStyle -> {
   Opacity[.25, Red]
   , Opacity[.25, Blue]
   , Opacity[.25, Darker@Green]
   }
 , FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, 18]
 , ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log"}, ImageSize -> Large
 , PlotRange -> {{0.0001, 0.03}, All}
 , PlotRangePadding -> {{2, 0.1}, {2, 0.1}}
 , FrameLabel -> {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(l\), \(\(displ\)\(.\)\)]\) \
[mm]", "Fraction"}, 
 PlotLabel -> 
  Style[Row[{"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(l\), \(decay\)]\) = 0.01 mm"}], 18,
    Black], 
 ChartLegends -> 
  Placed[SwatchLegend[{Directive[Opacity[0.25], Red]}, {"Before IP"}
    , LegendMarkerSize -> 30], {0.2, 0.9}]
 ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not understanding the use of the term "CDF" in the function `CDFforPoisson` as the equation being `Solve`d is related to the probability of a zero for a Poisson distribution and it doesn't need `Solve` in that `CDFforPoisson` could be written as

```
CDFforPoisson[u_]:=-Log[u]/100
```

If `u` has a uniform distribution, then the pdf of $-\log(u)/100$ is known and no random samples are necessary:

```
dist = TransformedDistribution[-Log[u]/100, u \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{0, 1}]]
(* ExponentialDistribution[100] *)
PDF[dist, x]
```

[image: PDF of exponential distribution with parameter = 100]

I'm not seeing the need to use a log scale for either horizontal or vertical axis.  Also, the vertical axis represents the "probability density" which is not a "Fraction" (or a percentage) as labeled.

Am I totally not understanding the question?